# Get Video URL from Media Entity reference field

Tags: 8, media

I have an entity reference field to Media Video.

I'm trying to get the uri to the video file in node template.

Most of the solution I found around is regarding Image/File. But not Video.

Tried [Twig Field Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) module but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the media type *Video* installed by core, you'll find the URL in the field `field_media_video_file`:

```
{{ file_url(node.field_media.entity.field_media_video_file.entity.uri.value) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the raw url of a remote video field in twig (Drupal 9):
`{{ node.field_media.entity.field_media_oembed_video.0.value }}`

Answer (score 0):

to display the raw url of a **remote video** :

```
{{ content.field_media_oembed_video.0 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I obtained the raw url using the following.

```
content.field_video_link.0['#media'].field_media_oembed_video.0.value
```

Where field_video_link was my custom field.