# Best practice for getting field values of entity chains

Tags: entities

I really would like to make this if/else field value check just a little bit more sexy.

What's Best Practice for dealing with nested functions chains to get entity field values (check if they exist / check if they are not empty)

```
 if($entity->hasField('field_intro_teaser_image_media_')){
      $media_field = $entity->field_intro_teaser_image_media_;

      if($media_field->entity){
        $media_field_entity = $media_field->entity;

        if($media_field_entity->hasField('field_media_image')){
          $media_field_entity_image = $media_field_entity->field_media_image;

          if($media_field_entity_image){
            $media_field_entity_image_entity = $media_field_entity_image->entity;

            if($media_field_entity_image_entity){
              $media_field_entity_image_entity_uri = $media_field_entity_image->entity->getFileUri();

              if($media_field_entity_image_entity_uri){

                // ... yay we got the damn uri!

              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The one liner would be:

```
$media_field = $entity->field_intro_teaser_image_media_->entity->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri();
```

Comment: Not tried it on entity fields yet, but [Null-safe operator](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/null-safe-operator)?

Comment: The one liner would fail if anything in the chain does not have the field or relational entity, so you'd want to wrap it in a try catch statement.

Comment: Or use Twig, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271579/get-video-url-from-media-entity-reference-field. Twig is null safe by default, if you don't set strict_variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access fields by magic methods, you don't actually have to check for their existence by using `hasField()` method.:

```php
$entity->field_that_does_not_exist->entity; // NULL.
$entity->get('field_that_does_not_exist'); // Exception.
$entity->get('field_that_does_not_exist')->entity; // Exception.
```

Using `$entity->field_intro_teaser_image_media_->entity` is sufficient in this case, if the field does not exist, the expression will be simply `NULL`, without any errors.

But of course you still have to check if referenced `->entity` is not `NULL`. PHP 8.0 Null-safe operator may be a way to do it, as suggested by [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive).

```php
$media_field = $entity
  ->field_intro_teaser_image_media_
  ->entity
  ?->field_media_image
  ->entity
  ?->getFileUri();
```

In case of using Null-safe operator, it will be probably faster to access entity fields by `->get()`, to avoid additional logic.

```php
$media_field = $entity
  ->get('field_intro_teaser_image_media_')
  ?->entity
  ?->get('field_media_image')
  ?->entity
  ?->getFileUri();
```

Comment: thank you . Love the Null Safe Operator. Never used it so far.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've built the chain correctly, you can do it as follows:

```
$media_field = NULL;
try {
  $media_field = $entity->field_intro_teaser_image_media_->entity->field_media_image->entity->getFileUri();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
  watchdog_exception('Media retrieval');
}

if (!is_null($media_field)) {
  // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I Did it this way.